# If $x_n\to0$ and $(x_{n+1}-x_n)/x_n^p$ converges then $\sum x_n$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $p>1$ be a real number and $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that
>    $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=0$$
>   and such that $\Big\{\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_n^p}\Big\}$ is convergent with a non-zero limit. Is it true that $\sum x_n$
>   converges if and only if $p<2$ ?

From the given condition it is immediate that $\sum x_n^p$ is convergent , but I cannot proceed further.

Comment: Summary of the proof. First note that the nonzero limit of the ratios $(x_n)^{-p}(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ is negative (if the limit is positive, the sequence $(x_n)$ is positive and ultimately increasing, hence $(x_n)$ cannot have limit $0$). Thus, $x_{n+1}\leqslant x_n-a(x_n)^p$ for every $n$ large enough, for some positive $a$. Next, pick some positive $b<(p-1)a$ and deduce that, for every $n$ large enough, $$(x_{n+1})^{1-p}\geqslant b+(x_n)^{1-p}\qquad(\ast)$$ hence $(x_n)^{1-p}\geqslant nb+c$ for every $n$, for some finite $c$, which implies that $x_n=O(1/n^r)$ with $r=1/(p-1)$. If $p<2$, then (...)

Comment: (...) $r>1$ hence the series $\sum x_n$ converges. Likewise, pick some positive $b'>(p-1)a$, then, for every $n$ large enough, $$(x_{n+1})^{1-p}\leqslant b'+(x_n)^{1-p}\qquad(\ast\ast).$$ This implies that $(x_n)^{1-p}\leqslant nb'+c'$ for every $n$, for some finite $c'$, hence $x_n=\Omega(1/n^r)$. If $p\geqslant2$, then $r\leqslant1$ hence the series $\sum x_n$ diverges. In the end, the proof is reduced to show $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$, that is, that, for every $a$ and every $p>1$, $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\,[(x-ax^p)^{1-p}-x^{1-p}]=(p-1)a.$$ The limited (...)

Comment: (...) expansion $$(x-ax^p)^{1-p}=x^{1-p}(1-ax^{p-1})^{1-p}=x^{1-p}(1+a(p-1)x^{p-1}+o(x^{p-1})),{}{}{}$$ that is, $$(x-ax^p)^{1-p}=x^{1-p}+a(p-1)+o(1),$$ then completes the proof.

Comment: @Did : I am able to get $(x_n-ax_n^p)^{1-p} < b'+(x_n)^{1-p}$ for large $n$ ; also since $1-p<0$ , so $(x_n-ax_n^p)^{1-p} \le ( x_{n+1})^{1-p}$ ; from these two , how do we get $( x_{n+1})^{1-p} \le  b'+(x_n)^{1-p}$  ? 
The rest is fantastic you have done :)

Comment: Start from $x_{n+1}\geqslant x_n-a'(x_n)^p$ for every $n$ large enough, for some positive $a'$, then pick $b'>(p-1)a'$, then...

Comment: @Did Why don't you post these comments as an answer?